# How to convert char array elements to int and the other way in c?

Tags: c, arrays, char, int, typeconverter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define lim 80

int
main ()
{
  char c[lim], a[lim];
  int n, i, p, j;

  do
  {
      puts ("Uneti broj elemenata niza")        //enter the number of array elements//;                                                                        
      scanf ("%d", &n);
  }
  while (n <= 0 || n > lim);

  puts ("Uneti clanove niza");  //enter the array elements//                    
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      scanf ("%c", &c[i]);
      p = int (c[i]);           //my attempt to convert char to int//           
      if (p >= 65 && p <= 90 || p >= 97 && p <= 122)    //if c[] array element is a letter put it also in a[] array//                                          
      {
          a[j] = char (p);      //my attempt to convert int to char//           
          j++;
      }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      printf ("%c ", a[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Why won't it compile?

```
zad.c: In function ‘main’:
zad.c:20:3: error: expected expression before ‘int’
zad.c:23:6: error: expected expression before ‘char’
```

Comment: Please be very careful when reindenting code this bad, folks.  Y'all removed one of the bugs!

Answer (score 3):

The compiler thinks you're declaring a new int with this line

```
p=int(c[i]);
```

Try

```
p=(int)(c[i]);
```

to cast c[i] as an int.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have commented out the semicolon on the line

   ```
   puts ("Uneti broj elemenata niza")        //enter the number of array elements//;
   ```

   `//` comments end at the end of the line; nested `//` has no effect.
2. C is not C++.  Writing

   ```
   variable = type(expression);
   ```

   is valid only in C++.  To do what that does in C, you write

   ```
   variable = (type) (expression);
   ```
3. To determine whether a `char` value is a letter, you need not convert it to an `int` nor need you compare it against hard-coded manually looked up ASCII code points.  Instead, use the functions from [`ctype.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/ctype.h.html):

   ```
   scanf("%c",&c[i]);
   if (isalpha(c[i])
   {
       a[j] = c[i];
       j++;
   }
   ```
4. [Never use `scanf`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).